# Is it safe for me to move to the coast?

Tags: climate-change, sea-level

I live in Brazil, around 200 km from the nearest coast.

I'm looking to move to Rio de Janeiro (a coastal city) to study at the Federal University of Rio, which is basically on an island ([Ilha do Fundão](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Ilha+do+Fund%C3%A3o/)). It's not an elevated place, just a common coastal site. It is an area of almost no seismic activity, and not a spot with a hurricane history.

I'd be there for at least 5 years to complete my degree.  But I've never lived in a coastal city and have heard there's concern of changes that could be dangerous.

Among the things I'm worried about: is the sea level rising... and is it going to happen rapidly? Is it so much that I could drown while I'm at a class or something?
Even if it doesn't happen quickly, could the University be destroyed and make me unable to finish my courses?

What are the predictions for the next 5 years?  Are the expected changes ones that should make me reconsider my plans to move there there for that time period?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because homework questions are expected to show proof of prior research.

Comment: I'm not sure it's homework, it's certainly possible.  if it's not Nobody, search for questions here about sea level rise predictions.  Or edit your question so it doesn't start so broadly.

Comment: To all: This was made a poor question by someone's excessive edit, which made it look like a cold homework question rather than an honest reasonable question from a new user.  I hope we'll reconsider it.

Comment: @JeopardyTempest thank you man. I don't know what happened but that's not what I wrote. I don't even know the word "geohazards". It was sort of a personal question that I could've expressed in some other way.

Comment: Sea level rise is a concern for coastal cities on timescales of decades -- 20, 30, 50 years. The sea rises by millimeters per year, and cities may sink by centimeters per year. Even if all of the change of a decade would happen at once, while you're in class, the worst that would happen is that you're ankle deep in water. But the change does not happen all at once.

Comment: As @WolfgangBangerth mentioned, it will take time. Enough time for many coastal cities to prepare in some manner. The future of Miami, FL might be a 21st century Venice.

Comment: this is one of the best sources for understanding sea level rise https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/hazards/sealevelrise/sealevelrise-tech-report.html i think most people in the world are asking this question in some shape or form.it can be answered and there is a lot of good peer rewiewed sources about this.

Comment: Global average SLR is approaching 5mm per year. https://climatefeedback.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/sea-level-rise.png . Tropical oceans have faster sea level rise but even at 10mm per year we shouldn't expect more than 50mm of sea level rise in places like Rio over the next 5 years. It will be places already getting high tide + storm surge inundation that are at risk. Storm, flood and mudslides seem like greater risks for the next 5 years than Sea Level Rise.

Answer (score 7):

Sea Level Rise owing to [climate change](https://climate.nasa.gov/vital-signs/global-temperature/) is happening. But relative to human life spans, and the length of a study course, it is very slow.

Waves from storms could be a problem, but the school is reasonably well protected within Guanabara Bay.

Storm surge could be a problem, if wind directions, and tides align. But you could reduce this risk my signing up for weather warnings.

During heavy rain, you may find that surface water can flow down streets etc. which can be dangerous is short term. This could happen anywhere though.

In most coastal cities it would be very rare to have flooding over 5 meters in depth. If you are worried perhaps pick accomodation on 2nd floor, or above. But really this is just for peace of mind.

Go study & have fun.